# Entity Framework Select with many tables One-to-Many

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, select, entity-framework-core

With the three tables below:

[image]

Relationship:

1. Author is one-to-one with AuthorBiography
2. Author is one-to-many with AuthorPrix

and I would perform a query using method syntax in EF Core and Select to limit the fields to return.

```
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, ab.Biography, ap.PrixName
FROM dbo.Author AS a
LEFT JOIN dbo.AuthorBiography AS ab ON a.AuthorId = ab.AuthorRef
LEFT JOIN dbo.AuthorPrix AS ap ON a.AuthorId = ap.AuthorRef
```

I can do like that:

```
var a = dbCtx.Author
                .Include(b => b.AuthorBiography)
                .Include(c => c.AuthorPrixes)
                .Select(a => new { a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.AuthorBiography.Biography })
                .ToList();
```

But I cannot add the field [Prix Name] to the select.
Is still possible using a simple Select or I should use a Join?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `SelectMany` to your linq query like this:

```
var a = dbCtx.Author
        .Include(b => b.AuthorBiography)
        .Include(c => c.AuthorPrixes)
        .SelectMany(a => a.AuthorPrixes)
        .Select(a => new { a.PrixName, a.Author.FirstName, a.Author.LastName, a.Author.AuthorBiography.Biography })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Guys, why you add `Include` for custom projection?

Comment: Thanks for help, I forgot to reply to you and check the accepted answer flag.